# Is it possible to have arm-none-eabi-size (gcc-size) to show size in decimal (--radix=10) and address in hex (--radix=16)

Tags: size

I have today the following flags used for size

```
arm-none-eabi-size --format=SysV -x
```

But this shows both the section size and its address in hex. using -d gives everything in decimal. Is it possible to combine the two to have size in decimal and address in hex?

with -x:

```
    arm-none-eabi-size --format=SysV -x build/frog.elf
    build/frog.elf  :
    section                size         addr
    .isr_vector           0x298    0x8000000
    ...
```

with -d:

```
    arm-none-eabi-size --format=SysV -d build/frog.elf
    build/frog.elf  :
    section               size        addr
    .isr_vector            664   134217728
    ...
```

I would like:

```
    arm-none-eabi-size --format=SysV -??? build/frog.elf
    build/frog.elf  :
    section               size        addr
   .isr_vector            664   0x8000000
   ...
```

Comment: I'd like to know this too.